# Sparql result not containing specified property included in results

Tags: sparql, dbpedia, virtuoso

I have this query

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/>
PREFIX dbpedia_property: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
PREFIX dbpedia_ontology: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX yago: <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/>
PREFIX schema: <http://schema.org/>

SELECT * WHERE
{
    {
        SELECT ?school
        WHERE
        {
            ?school rdf:type yago:EducationalInstitution108276342 .
            FILTER ( contains(str(?school), "Australia") )
        }
        ORDER BY ?school
    }
}
```

Don't mind the extra brackets as this is part of a larger query.
What I want to know is why thi http://dbpedia.org/page/Academic_structure_of_the_Australian_National_University is included in the results since I specify `rdf:type yago:EducationalInstitution108276342`. This property is not included in the resource page. I'm using this endpoint: http://dbpedia.org/sparql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a bug in the Pubby Web interface or in the query that is used to get the data that will be shown.

The query

```
SELECT * WHERE{
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Academic_Structure_of_the_Australian_National_University> ?p ?o
}
```

returns the necessary `rdf:type` statement.

The other strange thing is that even a SPARQL DESCRIBE query does not return the `rdd:type` triples:

```
DESCRIBE <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Academic_Structure_of_the_Australian_National_University>
```

Although DESCIBE is not really defined in the specs, a user would expect those triples for sure. And maybe this kind of query is used to retrieve the data for the Web pages of resources.

Comment: Thank you for help. Do you know where we can report this?

Comment: I would suggest the Virtuoso Users mailing list: https://sourceforge.net/p/virtuoso/mailman/virtuoso-users/ or even opening a Github issue: https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues